# Time series in spectrogram() and spectrum()

Tags: fft, python, spectrogram

I'm trying to create an order map for order analysis from my accelerometer data. To do that I want to resample my acceleration data and their time stamps in python.
I found `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram()` and `scipy.signal.spectrogram()` and both of them pretty much calculate the arrays for the plots. However, the input is only *my signal array* and the function returns: (1) 2-D spectrum array, (2) 1-D frequencies array, (3) 1-D time array

I want to know how the time array is calculated so that I can use my resampled time array. Or maybe someone knows of another way of doing this?

Comment: I think that you are mixing stuff up. For the simplest case, you integrate the angular speed by cumsum and then interpolate the acceleration function using a new angular vector that you create manually. The output signal is what you are looking for.

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan I'm sorry. I didn't mention that I've a pulse array, which increases every time the shaft completes one rotation. My idea was to get the index of where a new pulse occurs, get the corresponding time and acceleration and then interpolate, so that for every rotation I'd have like 256 samples for acceleration and time each. 
Is this what you mean?
My spectrogram would be (x-axis: time, y-axis: order). But then my time array won't be distributed equally along the whole time array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for but the formula to calculate time array in spectrogram for MATLAB is :

t = $((colindex-1)+((nwind)/2)') /Fs$;

where colindex is the starting index of columns along which time increases and nwind is the length of the window. The elements in t are centered in the segment.

colindex is calculated by $colindex= 1 + (0:(ncol-1))*(nwind-noverlap)$;

ncol is the number of columns of the STFT output 
$ncol = fix((nx-noverlap)/(nwind-noverlap))$;

noverlap is the number of overlapped samples.

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement this and see if I get the desired result.